# Identify this telephony or data connector?

Tags: identification, connector, telecommunications

Recently I had the opportunity to visit a telecom/data room that was being decommissioned. A lot of the remaining equipment seemed to be from around year 2000 or so, as best as I could tell.

While there I spotted a bundle of wires with connectors that were new to me. Most of them looked like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

These pics show a 2, 4 and 6-wire types; 2-wire was the most common.

Both ends of the cables had this type of connector.

Unfortunately they were all unattached and I did not see anything that looked like they would plug into.

So far I've not been able to turn these up in any web searches. What are they and what are they used for? Were or are they especially common?

Comment: looks like a power cable ... please add the end view ... what is at the other end of the cable?

Comment: That looks a lot like something I knew as a "110 patch panel connector" when I used to do network installations about 20 years ago. It's probably CAT5 rated and good for 100Mbps Ethernet.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/110_block